# Expected a list of items but got type "dict" PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I am connecting to an API and got this error when passing the following data format:

```
 $data = array(
            "from_date" => "2021-11-10",
            "to_date" => "2021-11-21",
            "adults" => 1,
            "guest_id" => 2954339,
            "stay_type" => "GUEST",
            "entities" => [ "property_id" => 89835 ]
        );
        $reservation = fetch_api('reservations', '', 'POST', $data);
```

The error:

```
 [message] => Expected a list of items but got type "dict".
 [code] => not_a_list
```

The issue is with the `entities` value. I believe it is because it is an array. Below is my `fetch_api` function. Which works fine when connecting to other endpoints and sending data without nested array.

```
function fetch_api($endpoint, $parameters = '', $method = 'GET', $data = null){
        $curl = curl_init();
        $headers = array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: Token xxxxxx",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
        );
        if ($method == 'GET') {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        }

        if ($method == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        }
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.lodgix.com/public-api/v2/'. $endpoint .'/' . $parameters);
        

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($result);
        if (!$result) {
            die("Connection Failure");
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
    }
```

I have tried to `json_encode` the nested array like below:

```
if ($method == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    
            if ($data) {
                for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
                    if (gettype($data[$i]) === 'array') {
                        json_encode($data[$i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        }
```

Unfortunately, it did not help. Am I on the right track in believing the issue is with the nested array or the issue is completely different?

Comment: [message] => Expected a list of items but got type "dict".
 [code] => not_a_list

Comment: Try `"entities" => [ 89835 ]`

Comment: Can you do a echo print_r(json_encode($data), true); ?

Comment: @ChrisHaas If do that it changes the error to: `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.`

Comment: @WynnTeo It won't print it anywhere.

Comment: Try passing a "list of items" (whatever the API means by that) as `$data`; maybe `"entities" => "89835,89836"`? Or maybe `$data` needs to be wrapped inside `[]`?

Comment: echo print_r(json_encode($data), true), it return a valid json data. {"from_date":"2021-11-10","to_date":"2021-11-21","adults":1,"guest_id":2954339,"stay_type":"GUEST","entities":{"property_id":89835}}

Comment: I try to access the lodgix API with the above JSON data, I am able to get the results without error. {
    "count": 0,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": []
}

Comment: _"I have tried to json_encode the nested array like below"_ - you just called `json_encode($data[$i])` in the loop there, but you are not doing anything with the return value - so what's the point of calling it in the first place then?

Comment: @WynnTeo Thanks for giving it a try. I managed to print it and the JSON returns valid. I also manage to get a valid response if connecting with Postman. Something seems to be causing this in my `fetch_api` function. Any guesses?

Comment: @MartinZeitler The API requires that specific format. Which workds if I use Postman. Something is not working in the code. What does the error even mean? `Expected a list of items but got type "dict"`. What is `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when using json_encode and a json structure required by servers that produce this kind of error, the list data is required within two arrays such as:

```
$data = array(
    "from_date" => "2021-11-10",
    "to_date" => "2021-11-21",
    "adults" => 1,
    "guest_id" => 2954339,
    "stay_type" => "GUEST",
    "entities" => array([ "property_id" => 89835 ])
);
$reservation = fetch_api('reservations', '', 'POST', $data);
```